# How To Call an MVC5 Action from Javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jscript

I am trying to update a table (based on user input of a view) with Javascript. Up until the `alert("We Made it This Far")` everything seems to be working. Then I get the `alert("Failed")`.

I placed a breakpoint on the first line of the controller. When running in debug I never hit that breakpoint. So I am thinking we never actually reach the controller.

I have tried many variations of the URL to reach the controller, and I am pulling my hair out.

My controller is `NewOrderController.cs`. My action is `SaveData`

I will post my code below.  I didn't think the controller code was needed, as I don't think I am even getting that far to see if that is working. However, if that code is needed, just let me know and I will also post it.

```js
$("#addsupply").click(function() {
  var RequisitionNumber = document.getElementById("reqlabel").textContent;
  var UnitsOrdered = document.getElementById('HowMany').value;

  var e = document.getElementById("SuppliesList");
  var SuppliesID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if (UnitsOrdered.trim() == "" || SuppliesID.trim() == "") {
    alert("You Must Select a Supply AND Enter The Amount of Supplies to Order!");
    return false;
  }

  alert("we made it this far")
  // here call server side function for save data using jquery ajax

  $.ajax({
    url: "../NewOrder/SaveData",
    // url: '@Url.Action("NewOrder", "SaveData")',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "RequisitionNumber": RequisitionNumber,
      "UnitsOrdered": UnitsOrdered,
      "SuppliesID": SuppliesID
    }),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.d == "success") {
        alert("Data saved successfully");
        // clear text here after save complete
        $('#HowMany').val('');
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      // alert(thrownError);
      alert("failed");
    }
  }).done(function() {
    alert("we did it");
  });
});
```

Edit:  Adding Codefor SaveData Method:

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string SaveData(string RequisitionNumber, int UnitsOrdered, int SuppliesID)
    {

        string status = "";
        // apply validation here
        ICS_Orders c = new ICS_Orders { LineID = 0, RequisitionNumber = RequisitionNumber, UnitsOrdered = UnitsOrdered, SuppliesID = SuppliesID };

        // here MyDatabaseEntities  is our dbContext
        using (ICSContext dc = new ICSContext())
        {
            dc.ICS_Orders.Add(c);
            dc.SaveChanges();
            status = "success";
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

}

Second Edit: Below is my error that I am getting from Fidder.  Resource Not Found.  I have tried every which way (but loose) to add the url and nothing seems to work.  Don't understand why it can't find my controller method.  It is inside my controller folder . . is that an issue?

```
        <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

        <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
        <br><br>

        <b> Requested URL: </b>/NewOrder/SaveData<br><br>
```

Comment: Check the console for the exact error of the response. I'd suggest un-commenting the `@Url.Action()` call so you know the URL will be correct.

Comment: Please show what your `SaveData` method looks like.

Comment: @jcruz - I have added the SaveData method code.

Comment: Try adding the [FromBody] parameter binding to your method. Read here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update MVC action syntax:

from

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveData(string RequisitionNumber, int UnitsOrdered, int SuppliesID)
```

to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(string RequisitionNumber, int UnitsOrdered, int SuppliesID)
```

Also, 
(1) just a side note on better practices: Instead of boat loading your function with various parameters, you can create a class with those properties and let MVC take care of mapping to correct properties via serialization.

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SaveData", "Orders")"  method="post">
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveData", "Orders", new {}, FormMethod.Post)) // Please check the syntax here.
```

(2) Is there a reason why you are not using form post? Are you using razor views or something else? if razor, you can use @Html.BeginForm

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up using @Html.BeginFom, as you suggested.